# Unity3d Move player with UI buttons

Tags: unity, movement, rigidbody

I'm trying to move the player based on UI buttons. I found this topic which covers the button listener: https://forum.unity.com/threads/touch-and-hold-a-button-on-new-ui.266065/#post-1944748

Now I know when the button is being pressed, but how can I "connect" those two scripts to make the player move?

I have this script to the player which was moving without using button.

```
public class player : MonoBehaviour {
     Rigidbody m_Rigidbody;
     public float m_Speed;

     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {                
         m_Rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
         //Set the speed of the GameObject    
     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () {
         /* OLD -> WITHOUT BUTTON

         float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
         float y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

         x = -x;

         m_Rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2( x * m_Speed,  y * m_Speed);
         */
     }
 }

 public class scrLeftButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler {

     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {        

     }        

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () {
         if (!isPressed) {
             return;
         }
     }

     bool isPressed = false;

     public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData){
         isPressed = true;
     }

     public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData){
         isPressed = false;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Class names should have their first letter capitalized
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
     public float movementSpeed;
     private Rigidbody rigidbody;
     public PlayerButton LeftButton; // Drag & drop the left button object
     public PlayerButton RightButton; // Drag & drop the right button object;
     public PlayerButton UpButton; // Drag & drop the up button object;
     public PlayerButton DownButton; // Drag & drop the down button object;

     // Use this for initialization
     void Start ()
     {                
         rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
     }

     // FixedUpdate must be used when you manipulate the physics components
     void FixedUpdate ()
     {
         Vector2 velocity = Vector2.zero ;
         if( RightButton.IsPressed ) velocity.x += movementSpeed ;
         if( LeftButton.IsPressed )  velocity.x -= movementSpeed ;
         if( UpButton.IsPressed )    velocity.y += movementSpeed ;
         if( DownButton.IsPressed )  velocity.y -= movementSpeed ;

        rigidbody.velocity = velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
     }

 // Attach this script to your 4 buttons.
 public class PlayerButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerExitHandler
 {
     // Define a property so that other classes can know whether the button is pressed
     public bool IsPressed
     {
         get ;
         private set ;
     }

     public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
     {
         IsPressed = true;
     }

     public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
     {
         IsPressed = false;
     }

     public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
     {
         IsPressed = false;
     }
 }
```

Comment: It worked! The only thing i had to change was the return type of IsPressed method to bool. Thank you!

Comment: My bad, I fixed the answer.
Thanks for your feedback !

Answer (score 0):

This is your old way of moving the character:

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
     float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
     float y = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

     x = -x;

     m_Rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2( x * m_Speed,  y * m_Speed);
 }
```

If you want to replace that with UI buttons, simply set the value of `x` and `y` based on the buttons. For example, when the right arrow is pressed, you could set `x` to `1.0` and for left arrow `-1.0`. Do the same for `y`.

One way to do this, is to give a reference of each button to the player, then you could do something like:

```
// Initialise to no button pressed
float x = 0;

// If a button is pressed, change x's value
if (myLeftArrow.IsPressed())
    x = -1;
```